# Next.JS 13 with useState inside global Context

Tags: react-hooks, react-context, saas, next.js13

I'm creating an app that uses Next.JS latest (13) and my app has pretty horizontal functionality meaning I want to have a context globally across many components, without entering into `prop` hell.

I've set up 2 `context`s, one for some variables, and for my user:

```
"use client";

export const MainContext = createContext<AppContextValues>({
  metadata: null,
  setMetadata: () => {},
  lastElement: null,
  setLastElement: () => {},
});

export const AppContext = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  console.log("setting up Appcontext");

  const [metadata, setMetadata] = useState(null);
  const [lastElement, setLastElement] = useState(null);

  return (
    <MainContext.Provider
      value={{
        metadata,
        setMetadata,
        lastElement,
        setLastElement,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </MainContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const AuthContext = createContext<UserContextValues>({
  state: initialState,
  setState: () => {},
  dispatch: () => {},
});

export const UserContext = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const dispatch = (value: Action) => {
    setState(value);
    executeAction(value);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        state,
        setState,
        dispatch,
      }}
    >
      <Authenticator />
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useMainContext = () => {
  return useContext(MainContext);
};

export const useAuthContext = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```

You'll notice that here above, since I'm using `useState`, Next.JS requires me to make the component a Client-side component with `"use client"` at the top.

The way I'm using the contexts is wrapping my entire app with `UserContext` so that I can access the user's state anywhere:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head></head>
      <body className="wrapper">
        <Header />
        <UserContext>
          <Navbar />
          <Clientpage />
          {children}
        </UserContext>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

And wrapping my main client page (`page.tsx)` with the `AppContext`:

```
"use client";

export const Clientpage = () => {
  const { state } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <AppContext>
      {state.user ? (
        <MainPage />
      ) : (
        <div className="lobby-screen">
          <SplashModal />
          <EmailLogin />
        </div>
      )}
    </AppContext>
  );
};
```

I'm not sure, but I think it's making my `AppContext` re-render every time MainPage is being changed/updated, which `null`s my `metadata` and `lastElement` states...

I'm new to the Next.JS framework so it's a bit confusing, would appreciate assistance :)

I've watched several tutorials specifically on this topic, and tried to understand the documentation on the Next.JS docs, but since I'm new to this, I can't get my head around this problem.

All of the examples use "regular" variables like `numbers` or `strings` in the value of the `Context Provider`, and not `useState`.

I'm expecting to set the context once and be able to modify it's values from my client OR server side, without it being reset.